# Creating a function from current source code "list comprehension"

Tags: python

Outcome 1 required:

The first batch of code below is in its working form.
Please assist in creating a function " def Calculations():" inclusive of all the list calculations to return the same results with the static list. With the calculations in proper functions I will be able to refine the problem and might be able to move forward ...

Outcome 2 required for those that want to go in depth...:
When I run the code on a live list that appends every x intervals it stalls the information feed. I believe it could be the creating of the appending lists in batches of increasing numbers... but I don't have a solution for it... Below is the working code...

I am getting my live data from Binance in a appending list of closes only for those who would like to test it in the live status...
The data could be coming from any source , does not need to be Binance as long as its an appending list of closes in float format...

See code below...

```
import itertools

l = [16.329,16.331, 16.3705, 16.3965, 16.44, 16.4227, 16.4028, 16.37, 16.3829, 16.3482, 16.3614, 16.4191, 16.4008, 16.4048, 16.4076, 16.3724, 16.3599, 16.3872, 16.3794, 16.3528, 16.3886, 16.3904, 16.3815, 16.3864, 16.4254, 16.4411, 16.4151, 16.4338, 16.4212, 16.3819, 16.2857, 16.2703, 16.2408, 16.1938, 16.2038, 16.2035, 16.217, 16.2374, 16.2414, 16.2238, 16.1787, 16.2725, 16.2964, 16.3155, 16.238, 16.2149, 16.2992, 16.3568, 16.2793, 16.2467, 16.312, 16.3117, 16.3017, 16.3465, 16.3882, 16.3698, 16.307, 16.3328, 16.3311, 16.3466, 16.3382, 16.3703, 16.3502, 16.3661, 16.38, 16.3972, 16.4141, 16.393, 16.3769, 16.3683, 16.4136, 16.3774, 16.3709, 16.3179, 16.3019, 16.3149, 16.2838, 16.2689, 16.2602, 16.2679, 16.2921, 16.312, 16.3158, 16.3198, 16.2955, 16.303, 16.327, 16.356, 16.313, 16.3, 16.2806, 16.2634, 16.2856, 16.2702, 16.2136, 16.2782, 16.276, 16.2231, 16.2255, 16.1314, 16.0796, 16.1192, 16.0977, 16.1358, 16.1408, 16.1703]


####  VARIABLES & SETTINGS  ####
dataingestperiod = 17
original_list_count = len(l)
timeframed_list = l[-dataingestperiod:]
timeframed_list_count = len(timeframed_list)

def groupSequence(x): 
    it = iter(x) 
    prev, res = next(it), [] 
  
    while prev is not None: 
        start = next(it, None) 
  
        if start and start > prev: 
            res.append(prev) 
        elif res: 
            yield list(res + [prev]) 
            res = [] 
        prev = start 

def divbyZero(increasingcount,decreasingcount):
    try: return increasingcount/decreasingcount
    except ZeroDivisionError: return 0
    
def divbyZeroMain(increasingcountMain,decreasingcountMain):
    try: return increasingcountMain/decreasingcountMain
    except ZeroDivisionError: return 0


#### TIMEFRAMED LIST CALCULATIONS#####
listA_1 = (list(groupSequence(timeframed_list))) # obtain numbers in increasing sequence
# print(len(listA_1)) # number of increases in mixed format
listA = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(listA_1)) # remove double brackets to enable list count
increasingcount = len(listA)
decreasingcount = timeframed_list_count - increasingcount
trend = divbyZero(increasingcount,decreasingcount)


#### MAIN APPENDING LIST CALCULATIONS #####
listMain_1 = (list(groupSequence(l)))
listMain = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(listMain_1))
increasingcountMain = len(listMain)
decreasingcountMain = original_list_count - increasingcountMain
trendMain = divbyZeroMain(increasingcountMain,decreasingcountMain)

###Timeframed list increases-only appending to max last"dataingestperiod" perhaps problem on live feed data....###
increase_list_timeframed = []
for x in listA: 
        increase_list_timeframed.append(x)

### Main list increases only appending...####
increase_list_Main = []
for x in listMain: 
        increase_list_Main.append(x)


###Prints ON TIMEFRAMED LIST ####
print ("---------------")
print ("---------------")
print ("Timeframed list count set at max {}".format(timeframed_list_count))
print ("Count of decreases in timeframed list is {}".format(decreasingcount))
print ("Count of increases in timeframed list is {}".format(increasingcount))
print ("Current timeframed trend is {}".format(trend))
print ("---------------")
print ("---------------")


###Prints ON MAIN LIST ####
print ("Main appending list count so far is {}".format(original_list_count))
print ("Count of decreases in Main appending list is {}".format(decreasingcountMain))
print ("Count of increases in Main appending list is {}".format(increasingcountMain))
print ("Current Main trend is {}".format(trendMain))
```

The actual code as live to binance is listed below with the above code included. You also need to install "pip install python-binance" and "pip install websocket_client" got the binance access code from ParttimeLarry

Outcome 2 required: When run live that all calculations run uninterruptedly...

```
import itertools
import copy
import websocket, json, pprint, talib, numpy
from binance.client import Client
from binance.enums import *

#DATA FROM WEBSOCKETS########
SOCKET = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/linkusdt@kline_1m"


API_KEY = 'yourAPI_KEY'
API_SECRET ='yourAPI_Secret'

closes = []   # created for RSI indicator only using closes
in_position = False


client = Client(API_KEY, API_SECRET) # tld='us'

def order(side, quantity, symbol,order_type=ORDER_TYPE_MARKET):
    try:
        print("sending order")
        order = client.create_order(symbol=symbol, side=side, type=order_type, quantity=quantity)
        print(order)
    except Exception as e:
        print("an exception occured - {}".format(e))
        return False

    return True

    
def on_open(ws):
    print('opened connection')
   # start_time = datetime.datetime.now().time().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    # try:
    #     file = open("C:/GITPROJECTS/binance-bot/csvstats.txt","+a")
    #     file.write("New Session Open Connection Start at time {}\n".format(datetime.datetime.now())))
    
    # finally:
    #     file.close()

def on_close(ws):
    print('closed connection')
   
def on_message(ws, message):
    global closes, in_position
    
    print('received message')
    json_message = json.loads(message)
    pprint.pprint(json_message)

    candle = json_message['k']

    is_candle_closed = candle['x']
    close = candle['c']
    
     
    if is_candle_closed:
        print("candle closed at {}".format(close))
        closes.append(float(close))
              
        print("closes")
        print(closes)
        
        
        
                  
####################################################################################
########CALCULATIONS ON INDICATORS #################################################        
        
        # dataingestperiod = 5
        l = copy.deepcopy(closes)
        maincountofcloses = len(l)
        print ("Total count of closes so far {}".format(maincountofcloses))
                    
        ####  VARIABLES & SETTINGS  ####
        l = copy.deepcopy(closes)        
        dataingestperiod = 3
        original_list_count = len(l)
        #print ("Main list count so far is {}".format(original_list_count))
        timeframed_list = l[-dataingestperiod:]
        timeframed_list_count = len(timeframed_list)
        #print ("Timeframed list count set at max {}".format(timeframed_list_count))


        def groupSequence(x):
            it = iter(x)
            prev, res = next(it), []
            
            while prev is not None:
                start = next(it, None)
                
                if start and start > prev:
                    res.append(prev) 
                
                elif res:
                    yield list(res + [prev]) 
                    res = [] 
                    prev = start 

        def divbyZero(increasingcount,decreasingcount):
            try: return increasingcount/decreasingcount
            except ZeroDivisionError: return 0
    
        def divbyZeroMain(increasingcountMain,decreasingcountMain):
            try: return increasingcountMain/decreasingcountMain
            except ZeroDivisionError: return 0


        #### TIMEFRAMED LIST CALCULATIONS#####
        listA_1 = (list(groupSequence(timeframed_list))) # obtain numbers in increasing sequence
        # print(len(listA_1)) # number of increases in mixed format
        listA = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(listA_1)) # remove double brackets to enable list count
        increasingcount = len(listA)
        decreasingcount = timeframed_list_count - increasingcount
        trend = divbyZero(increasingcount,decreasingcount)
        

        #### MAIN APPENDING LIST CALCULATIONS #####
        listMain_1 = (list(groupSequence(l)))
        listMain = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(listMain_1))
        increasingcountMain = len(listMain)
        decreasingcountMain = original_list_count - increasingcountMain
        trendMain = divbyZeroMain(increasingcountMain,decreasingcountMain)
        

        increase_list_timeframed = []

        for x in listA: 
                increase_list_timeframed.append(x)

      
        increase_list_Main = []
        for x in listMain: 
                increase_list_Main.append(x)

        ###Prints ON TIMEFRAMED LIST ####
        print ("---------------")
        print ("---------------")
        print ("Timeframed list count set at max {}".format(timeframed_list_count))
        print ("Count of decreases in timeframed list is {}".format(decreasingcount))
        print ("Count of increases in timeframed list is {}".format(increasingcount))
        print ("Current timeframed trend is {}".format(trend))
        print ("---------------")
        print ("---------------")

        ###Prints ON MAIN LIST ####
        print ("Main appending list count so far is {}".format(original_list_count))
        print ("Count of decreases in Main appending list is {}".format(decreasingcountMain))
        print ("Count of increases in Main appending list is {}".format(increasingcountMain))
        print ("Current Main trend is {}".format(trendMain))
        # threading.Timer(10.0, divbyZeroMain).start()         
        # threading.Timer(10.0, divbyZero).start()            
                 
                 
# ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_open=on_open, on_close=on_close, on_message=on_message)
# ws.run_forever()
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_open=on_open, on_close=on_close, on_message=on_message)
ws.run_forever()
```

Comment: Please consider providing a [mre] and clear sample data with actual vs expected output.

Comment: Could you provide the code you are using to obtain the list from the live source.  It is more likely that the error comes from side effects affecting that part than from the logic of  the your calculation code itself.

Comment: I have updated to both request... see updates.

Comment: I would like to tackle my problem step by step. First step to the solution is " Placing the calculations in a function in the static mode" Can anyone help with step 1 please. This will help me to advance forward to the more difficult issue which is "running it live"....

Comment: Anyone out there that can help with outcome 1 please ???